# Request for another page from aspx site

Tags: c#, asp.net

it is possible to do a request for another page on internet from page_load? I mean if it is possible to aquire markup code with informations from another page and display them on my aspx site? For example something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UnknownType anotherSite = GetMarkupCode("www.fifa.com");
  //parse anotherSite
             .
             .
             .
  //display parsed informations
             .
             .
             .
}
```

If it is possible how can i do that? Many thanks for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User can use the WebClient class.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Stream data = webClient.OpenRead("http://www.fifa.com");
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(data);
string html = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

EDIT: A simpler version thanks to Lucas

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string html = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.fifa.com");
```

Comment: In this case, it's simpler to use just `string html = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.fifa.com");`, rather that open it as a stream.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that was there! Not used WebClient in a while. Have edited answer to include.

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what i want :) Thanks Robin Day and also Lucas Jones.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an iframe and set the source of the iframe as the requested page url?

Comment: My "assumption" is that he wants to parse the html in order to retrieve certain bits of information from it. Not just display the whole page in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

HttpWebRequest

http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/WebRequest/Working_with_HttpWebRequest_and_HttpWebResponse_in_ASPNET_114.aspx